# Did Krishna stay in touch with Pandavas after the war?

Tags: krishna

I read somewhere that Vidur informs Pandavas about Krishna’s death & they didn’t know about it until Vidur informs them. Also Vidur didn’t reveal this info on his own & only gives out the info after the Pandavas ask about Krishna.

Comment: Well obviously if Krsna has left his body he cannot inform the Pandavas about it (when actually he did send a message to Arjuna before it happened). And as regarding Vidura he doesn't tell the Pandavas about krsna's passing away. *Arjuna* tells the Pandavas about it.

Comment: Reading the Mausala Parva of the Mahabharatha would address this. It's not a huge section (for those who are influenced by the size of the chapter before reading it)